# How do you have a subquery in the alias definition of a column (in the AS statement)

Tags: sql, subquery, alias

Creating an alias for a result in a query is no problem

```
select VALUE as ALIAS from TABLE
```

But what if I want the alias to be dynamic? My first thought would be to have a subquery in the AS statement, but SQL hates it apparently.

```
select VALUE1 as (select VALUE2 from TABLE2 where A=B) from TABLE1
```

This throws an error:

> .Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: You can't do sth like this in a single query

Comment: In standard SQL, this is not possible: the list and names of columns must be fixed. You would need dynamic SQL, which is much more complex. Why would actually need to do this?

Comment: I can think of a host of reasons why it would be useful, but for this specific time I'm generating a CSV report daily, and this would be a simple way to have the column names update if they change field values in the database, since these are the names of the columns ultimately. There are other ways to accomplish it but was curious that there might be a way to have a variable alias

Answer (score 0):

first, aliases are just names they lives until query running. its useful when writing long complex queries and also if you have long ugly table names you can use alias for that. you can use `AS` or just simply `table_name alias` but you can't use as for set sub-queries.

Comment: I know what aliases are, just wanted to use them a little differently.